# Trouble with Canvas rendering in Safari/Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, canvas, opera

Been banging my head against this one for a while, and figured I'd turn to the experts for some advice.

I've made a jQuery snippet that grabs the values from a table and plots them in a line graph on a canvas element (also generated by the JS). All's well in Firefox and Chrome, but Safari and Opera aren't displaying the plotted points. I've reviewed in Firebug, Web Inspector debugger, JSLint, and checked the markup with the w3 validator, but still can't find anything glaringly obvious.  I've also tried including the canvas element in the HTML rather than generating it dynamically, as well as substituting a tag pair for the self-closing tag I've been using—all to no avail.

Any chance one of you guys could help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I draw lots of lines in Safari so I checked my code and the pattern is...

beginPath
moveTo
lineTo(s)
closePath or stroke

In your code moveTo is before beginPath, so I switched that in one of my apps and it stopped drawing, so try switching those around.

Comment: +100 for you, sir!  That's exactly what the problem was.  HUGE thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem of the time when you call stroke(). Try to call it only after the `for` loop, and try differents positions of the closePath call.

Comment: Tried pulling it out of the for loop and calling it both before and after the closePath call, but no dice.  I originally had the stroke call in the for loop because I only wanted that certain section of the path stroked, but is there a more sensible way to accomplish that?

Either way, I'm not sure it had much of an effect—still getting that blank element in Safari 4.